# Disallow mix of specific traits

Tags: scala, type-systems

Given:

```
trait Foo
trait Bar { this: Foo => }
trait NoBar { this: Foo => }
```

Is there a way a can trick the type system into disallowing:

```
new Foo with Bar with NoBar {}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And type erasure saves the day again:

```
trait Foo
trait Dummy[A]
trait Bar extends Dummy[Bar]{ this: Foo => }
trait NoBar extends Dummy[NoBar]{ this: Foo => }
new Foo with Bar with NoBar {}
```

This results in the following error:

```
illegal inheritance; anonymous class $anon inherits different
type instances of trait Dummy: Dummy[Bar] and Dummy[NoBar]
```